# How to store a url string into a json object in java

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am reading in this json

```
{"website": {"url": "http://www.google.com"}}
```

I store the string in an json object like this

```
//I make a network call to get the string
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(website_string);
```

I have no problem when I take the forward slash out. How can I keep the forward slashes in?

Comment: What exactly is the problem if you don't take out the slashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can achieve this:

```
string urlString = "http:\/\/mywebsite.com";
```

Now you can obtain the result from json and process it using

```
string url = urlString .replace('\', '');
```